# Is it possible to access more than one page allowance of a database request?

Tags: sql, url

Say I am accessing a website that limits the number of article summaries

Real Life Example:

```
http://uk.businessinsider.com/author/shana-lebowitz?page=1
```

Is it possible to get more than one page be rendered for example something like this:

```
http://uk.businessinsider.com/author/shana-lebowitz?page=1-10
```

Comment: Why the SQL tag?

Comment: will page=1 not be rendered into a sql command (where limit = $var(10))

Comment: no - you can't magically rewrite the URL to understand extended meanings - unless that is allowed by the url attributes in the first place.